# Schedule picker, best way to save in SQL

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, schedule

I am have to add  a feature in my personal project to the Register section. Users have to choose the schedule but I am wondering how to persist these data and how to ask exactly the user?

This is what I imagined as views:
[image: scheduling]

But how do you imagine the sql table?

PS: Please not that I am using Laravel/Bootstrap so if you know some package that can help me, i'll take it

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for something like this (in it's most simplest form)

[image]

You can then use SQL to determine what day of the week it is, and whether it's a morning or afternoon slot.

Let me know if you need an example SQL.

**Edit**

You could use something like this to figure it out:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date_time), '%a') AS day 
     , DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%p') AS am_pm
     , DATE(date_time) AS the_date
     , DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%T') AS the_time
  FROM schedules
 WHERE user_id = :user_id -- pass in user ID here as a bind param
```

[image]

This would make it easier in future if you decided you wanted to make it date/time based.

For what you're wanting though - you could get away with something like this table, simply storing the Day and Morning/Afternoon as a VARCHAR.

It'd work, but I reckon you'd be better off with something like the first example.

[image]

```
SELECT *
  FROM schedules
 WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, it's a recursive form. I mean, when you select monday, it's every monday. If you select Wednesday and Friday morning, it mean every week, you are free these days at morning... You understand? Because with your solution I think it's not for recursive week? You can show me an example SQL ?

Comment: Sure, give me a mo and I'll generate the update answer :)

Comment: Ah, I see. But it will be a very big table no? nb_users*7*2 no? Or I can sore only the selected days. At first, I imagined a to add a shedule table with these columns:
schedule_id, user_id, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday etc...

and every row will be 0:none or 1:AM or 2:PM or 3:both 

I think you solution is better and more flexible

Comment: When a user wants to change their schedule, you could always run `DELETE FROM schedules WHERE user_id = :user_id" _before_ you `INSERT` more rows of data (with the new options) for that user. That way you'd only have a maximum of 14 rows per user in that table.

Comment: Your initial thoughts thought about a column for each day and a flag for morning or afternoon would also work. If you've got the time, try each one - see what works best for you. Have a gander at this link too for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83633/discussion-between-doublesidedstickytape-and-olivier-zoletti).

Comment: I will go for this solution :) And what about the views? Do you think it's ok?